# Ansible use a template with blockinfile

Tags: jinja2, ansible, ansible-2.x

`blockinfile` appears to do basic subsitutions with `{{` templates. The documentation doesn't mention any templating capabilities.

However, it doesn't appear to be possible to do a full template, say with a loop. This fails with `template error while templating string: unexpected '%'`

```
  blockinfile:
    dest: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE CONFIG certs"
    block: |
      {% if certs %}
      bind *:443 ssl crt {% for cert in certs %}{{cert}} {{% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
```

This seems like a basic usecase, where I might like to do some one-off edits for a configuration file, but still need the power of templates.

Note that using `with_items` doesn't really do what I want here, because I need exactly 1 line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have an extra `{` in the template.

```
      bind *:443 ssl crt {% for cert in certs %}{{cert}} {{% endfor %}
```

should be

```
      bind *:443 ssl crt {% for cert in certs %}{{cert}} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah, dumb mistakes. I did eventually figure out how block in file works.